# Are there costs associated with inverse_of? Should we add it to relationships wherever possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The rails method :inverse_of can be used to build an in-memory association between objects, so that you can reduce queries in a database: http://mediumexposure.com/better-memory-associations-inverseof/

What are the costs associated with inverse_of? Why is it that we don't write inverse_of on every relationship that exists, to reduce queries?

Comment: +1, would really like to know. AFAIK i can only see benefits. Guess it will become a default behaviour in later rails version

Comment: that's what i'm wondering - it seems like this should be default included on every relationship. The only downside I could think of as a possibility is that maybe it could affect server performance if objects become larger as a result (maybe taking up a lot of memory?). This is not something I know much about though..

Comment: yup, but the downside would be seriously countered by the fact that you don't fetch the same object twice and don't have two copies of the same object in memory... The only reason i can see here is that it's not so frequent that you do something like `ParentObject.child_objects.first.parent_object`

Comment: I hope inverse_of becomes the default. In my opinion, reducing SQL queries isn't the biggest benefit, but rather avoiding counterintuitive behavior. Without inverse_of, if you update an object property without saving to DB immediately, then access that property through a different object (e.g. object2.object1.property), you'll get the old value (pulled from the DB). Seems like that would lead to unintentional application errors.

See the Rails Guide example: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#bi-directional-associations

Comment: The challenge with making it the default is that it's often not possible to infer the inverse relationship. For example, the belongs_to name isn't the singular of the has_many name. I think implementing an identity map would solve the problem in a more universal way. I think inverse_of is definitely a feature of AR that we should be encouraging people to use more.

Comment: One of my client apps is a legacy project that has some complex associations. Adding `:inverse_of` had some unexpected consequences, i.e. specs failing without good error messages, so we reverted it. However, I am using it from scratch on a couple other projects with no ill-effects.

Comment: Interesting, @BM5k, if you find out any further details that led to these failures, it could make for a good answer to this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From Ernie Miller's [talk at Railsconf 2013](http://www.confreaks.com/videos/2460-railsconf2013-an-intervention-for-activerecord) (around  15:30)

> [...] inverse_of is the oldest ActiveRecord feature you aren't using, and you totally should. [...]

Comment: Here's the talk with a working link since Justin.tv shut down: http://www.confreaks.com/videos/2460-railsconf2013-an-intervention-for-activerecord